# Am I doing leapfrog integration correctly?

Tags: integration, molecular-dynamics, numerical-integration

I wrote this minimal example to examine the Leapfrog integration algorithm.

However, I am not sure it is the correct algorithm, and the listing is giving the correct output.

Is this the Leapfrog algorithm?

**NOTE:** I am using the Lennard-Jones system.

**NOTE-2:** I am using C#.

```
using System;

public class Vec3
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Z { get; set; }

    public Vec3(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public static Vec3 operator +(Vec3 a, Vec3 b)
    {
        return new Vec3(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y, a.Z + b.Z);
    }

    public static Vec3 operator *(Vec3 vector, double scalar)
    {
        return new Vec3(scalar * vector.X, scalar * vector.Y, scalar * vector.Z);
    }

    public static Vec3 operator *(double scalar, Vec3 vector)
    {
        return new Vec3(scalar * vector.X, scalar * vector.Y, scalar * vector.Z);
    }

    public static Vec3 Zero
    {
        get { return new Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); }
    }
}

public class Atom
{
    public Vec3 Position { get; set; }
    public Vec3 Velocity { get; set; }

    public Atom() { }

    public Atom(Vec3 position, Vec3 velocity)
    {
        Position = position;
        Velocity = velocity;
    }
}

public class ArgonGasSimulation
{
    private const double Sigma = 3.4;
    private const double Epsilon = 1.0;

    #region [unused]
    private static double ComputePotential(double distance)
    {
        double r6 = Math.Pow(distance, 6);
        double r12 = Math.Pow(r6, 2);
        return 4 * Epsilon * ((Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) - (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance));
    }
    #endregion

    private static Vec3 ComputeForce(Vec3 position)
    {
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(position.X * position.X + position.Y * position.Y + position.Z * position.Z);
        double r6 = Math.Pow(distance, 6);
        double r12 = Math.Pow(r6, 2);
        double magnitude = 48 * Epsilon * ((Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) - 0.5 * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance) * (Sigma / distance)) / distance;
        return magnitude * position;
    }

    private static void Leapfrog(Atom atom, double timeStep)
    {
        Vec3 force = ComputeForce(atom.Position); // Compute force based on the current position
        Vec3 newPosition = atom.Position + atom.Velocity * timeStep
                            + 0.5 * force * timeStep * timeStep;

        Vec3 newForce = ComputeForce(newPosition);

        Vec3 newVelocity = atom.Velocity + (force + newForce) * timeStep * 0.5;

        // Update state
        atom.Position = newPosition;
        atom.Velocity = newVelocity;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        // Initial state
        Vec3 position = new Vec3(1.0, 2.0, 3.0); // initial position
        Vec3 velocity = new Vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // initial velocity

        double timeStep = 0.01;

        Atom atom = new Atom(position, velocity);

        // Leapfrog integration
        Leapfrog(atom, timeStep);

        // Output new position and velocity
        Console.WriteLine("New Position: ({0}, {1}, {2})", atom.Position.X, atom.Position.Y, atom.Position.Z);
        Console.WriteLine("New Velocity: ({0}, {1}, {2})", atom.Velocity.X, atom.Velocity.Y, atom.Velocity.Z);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
New Position: (1.00014244382518, 2.00028488765035, 3.00042733147553)
New Velocity: (0.028470372373851, 0.0569407447477019, 0.0854111171215529)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: At the end of main, you are printing the original position and velocity, rather than the new position and velocity that should be stored in the atom, e.g. `atom.position.X`. I didn't verify the logic otherwise, but just adding some print statements in `Leapfrog` shows that `newPosition` and `newVelocity` are different from the initial.

Comment: the main thing you are doing wrong is writing your own routine for integration rather than using a library

Comment: Really? For something as simple as Verlet Leapfrog, which should require no more than 2 or 3 lines of code? Out of curiosity which libraries offer an implementation of the Verlet algorithm or its variants?

Comment: @IanBush, Yeah?  OOP works like this. This is not Fortran or Python.

Comment: Last thing I shall say, but in Fortran I would call the appropriate interface to the relevant type bound procedure. In Julia I would call the appropriate method.. OOP is a state of mind, not of programming language, and is not the best solution in all cases. Again I don't understand why something as simple a a Verlet algorithm requires a full library, with all the support and installation issues that can entail. And is there a library that provides the Verlet algorithm?

Comment: There is the original Cromer-Newton-...-Verlet scheme that only uses positions. Then there is the variant using difference quotients to transform the second-order iteration into a first-order iteration. If those difference quotients get interpreted as half-step velocities, one gets a leapfrog algorithm. The variant where the velocities are taken at the time nodes via symmetric difference quotient, as is the case here, is usually called velocity Verlet. The differences are minimal, but when the variants have names, one should strive to use the correct ones.

Comment: Please mark or better avoid cross-postings, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074492/leapfrog-integration-to-update-position-and-velocity

Comment: @LutzLehmann, Please post an answer rather than only policing!

Comment: There is nothing wrong now with the code. For the variants of the methods see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/verlet-integration/info or my new answer in the cross-post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77074492/leapfrog-integration-to-update-position-and-velocity.